# Prevent circular reference with ModelMapper - List

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, circular-reference, modelmapper

I'm having a Json error because my DTO's are keeping a circular reference each other.

**CompanyDTO:**

```
@Data
public class CompanyDTO {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<CompanyCountryDTO> companyCountries;
    //getters and setters
}
```

**CompanyCountryDTO:**

```
@Data
public class CompanyCountryDTO {

    private Long id;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private CompanyDTO company;
    private CountryDTO country;
    //getters and setters
```

**CompanyService** implementation convert a list of **Company** to a list of **CompanyDTO**:

```
@Override
public List<CompanyDTO> getAllCompaniesWithCountryDTO() {
   List<Company> listCompanies = companyRep.findAll();
   return listCompanies.stream().map(this::convertToDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private CompanyDTO convertToDto(Company company) {
    CompanyDTO companyWithServiceDTO = modelMapper.map(company, CompanyDTO.class);
    return companyWithServiceDTO;
}
```

I would like to do something like this but using ModelMapper because I have others references that are circular:

```
listCompanies.stream().forEach(company -> {
    if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(company.getCompanyCountries())) {
        company.getCompanyCountries().forEach(companyCountry -> {
           companyCountry.setCompany(null);             
        });
    }
});
```

How can I remove company reference from CompanyCountryDTO since company also have another list of CompanyCountryDTO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you just need to skip the "back reference" to avoid circularity and infinite recursion. In this case the field `company` in `CompanyCountryDTO`.

To have it work configure your `ModelMapper` like:

```
modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<CompanyCountry, CompanyCountryDTO>() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // Tells ModelMapper to NOT populate company
        skip(destination.getCompany());
    }
});
```

Comment: I didn't know how to skip an object in a child list. I didn't know it was just mapping the entity. Thanks.

Comment: problem is this always skips it. even when we want don't wanna. what if i only want to skip it when mapping a CompanyDto and not when im mapping a CompanyCountryDTO ? and vise versa.

Answer (score 1):

http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/configuration/ says

> Prefer nested properties  | Determines if the implicit mapping should map the nested properties, we strongly recommend to disable this option while you are mapping a model contains circular reference   | true

So another fix might be to

```
getConfiguration().setPreferNestedProperties(false);
```